# report does not print all tables, All data is sent correctly from the API

Tags: c#

I have a problem with Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore, when the report is generated, only the data from the first table of the report is being filled, the rest of the tables are empty. (Each table has its own data set)

I already tried to create new datasets and it still doesn't work

Comment: Please add your code as well, without code nobody can help you.

Comment: don´t have code, is reporting service